# Print key, value pairs as a 2d table

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, formatting

I'm trying to turn my routing table into a nice printed table, but I'm having trouble with the format. I've included my code below.

So I want this :

```
╒══════╤══════╤══════╤══════╤══════╕
│ RA   │   H1  │   H2  │   RA │   RB  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ RA   │    1  │    4  │    0 │    1  │
├──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ RB   │    2  │    3  │    1 │    0  │
╘══════╧══════╧══════╧══════╧══════╛
```

But I'm getting this: (on a side note, it does not matter to have the complete column/row lines in there, as long as it comes out in table format)

```
RA         H1         H2         RA         RB        
-------------------------
H1 :  {1: 4}
RA :  {0: 1}
H2 :  {4: 3}
RB :  {1: 0}
-------------------------
```

```
self.rt_tbl_D = {'H1': {1: 4}, 'RA': {0: 1}, 'H2': {4:3}, 'RB': {1:0}}      # {destination: {router: cost}}
```

My code for printing is this:

```
print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format('RA', 'H1', 'H2', 'RA', 'RB'))
print('-------------------------')
for key, value in self.rt_tbl_D.items():
    print(key + ' : ', value)
print('-------------------------')
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is cheating to some extent as you don't (yet) mention how you come to populate RA or RB in the first column, but it shows you how you can use a comprehension to generate a list then use the [* operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/tuple_unpack.html) to unpack them into the print statements.

```
rt_tbl_D = {'H1': {1: 4}, 'RA': {0: 1}, 'H2': {4:3}, 'RB': {1:0}}      # {destination: {router: cost}}
keylist = ['RA', 'H1', 'H2', 'RA', 'RB']
print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(*keylist))
print('--------------------------------------------------')
print("RA         {:<10}  {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(*[k for key in keylist[1:] for k in rt_tbl_D[key].keys()]))
print("RB         {:<10}  {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(*[k for key in keylist[1:] for k in rt_tbl_D[key].values()]))
print('--------------------------------------------------')
```

Output:

```
RA         H1         H2         RA         RB        
--------------------------------------------------
RA         1           4          0          1         
RB         4           3          1          0         
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The values for the table are given for the first part of the project I'm working on. In the next steps I will be implementing routing tables for connected hosts.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes my apologies, this does answer my question and please allow me to clear up any confusion.
The first table with the 2 is from the instructions as an "Example" that was given information. I wanted to create a table and get it printing before I started generating routing tables and costs into them. so I hard coded the rt_tbl_D from my post above into my file to learn to navigate dictionaries as I'm not too familiar with Python. This worked and was what I was looking for, but I will more than likely have to change things around a little bit. Overall a great help and starting point!